# Google Calendar API Watch Channel Should I get a push notification for each resource?

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client, google-calendar-api

When subscribing to Calendar Channel, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push, should I expect to get a push notification for each new event created?

In testing, if I create 21 events (each at 2 second intervals), I get about 7 notifications.

It's hard to tell from the docs if I should be getting a notification for each event created, or if I should use the notification to do a sync?

What are you guys doing for your apps?

Answer (score 2):

Google Calendar watches only make sense when you're also using the sync token feature. They are basically instructions to do another sync, which will bring in 1 or more event changes. The reason you got less than 21 messages is because Google rate limits the messages (in your case to what looks like every ~3 seconds... my experience is closer to 10s).

The callout about not being 100% reliable is actually a bit of a different concern than the "only 7" callbacks issue. Until yesterday, my experience was that watches were 99.9% reliable in terms of delivering a notification within a few seconds of a change. But for the 0.1%, you'll want to have some sort of fallback force sync... could be once an hour, could be upon login, etc.

Comment: So if a user makes changes to multiple events in quick succession (for example, creates one, then immediately deletes another one, or update, etc, a reasonable scenario), and Google API only sends the notification for the first event, but not the ones done 2 seconds later, doesn't that mean our application is out of sync, because it only performed a sync (full or incremental doesn't matter) after receiving the first event notification, and missing the rest that occurred seconds later?

Comment: They will always send one more watch message at the end of the activity, they just throttle it in such a way that N changes doesn't always mean N watches. But they generally won't *not* send a final message, it might just be throttled/delayed. Of course, they also might miss delivery entirely, as they disclaim, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed similar.  Scroll down to the very bottom of that page you linked:

`Notifications are not 100% reliable. Expect a small percentage of messages to get dropped under normal working conditions. Make sure to handle these missing messages gracefully, so that the application still syncs even if no push messages are received.`

If you've called `watch` on the calendar to register/create a notification channel, I'm assuming they're doing some throttling/bucketing to push out notifications at a coarse-grained level.  Testing this out myself but I believe the original intention of asking for incremental changes via setting `timeMin` equal to a previously requested syncTime still holds true:

https://developers.googleblog.com/2013/07/google-calendar-api-push-notifications.html